# How to create Application class?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In this artical is this

> 4. Add your Parse API keys
>
> Create or open your Application class, and add the following line to
>   your onCreate method:
>
> Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY"); Make sure to
>   replace "YOUR_APP_ID" and "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY" with your Parse app's id
>   and client key. You can find these in your app's Settings page.

how to create and implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation for `android.app.Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html):

> You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

Specifically, the class name of your `Application` subclass would go in [the `android:name` attribute of the `<application>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm).